# Scala apply with no parameters

Tags: scala, subclass, apply

I want to create a program that generates random things when requested, such as letters in the below example. I've defined an abstract class with a companion object to return one of the subclasses.

```
  abstract class Letter

  class LetterA extends Letter {
    override def toString = "A"
  }
  class LetterB extends Letter {
    override def toString = "B"
  }
  class LetterC extends Letter {
    override def toString = "C"
  }

  object Letter {
    def apply = RNG.d(3) match {
      case 1 => new LetterA
      case 2 => new LetterB
      case 3 => new LetterC
    }
    override def toString = "Random Letter"
  }
```

The dream is that I'll be able to use `Letter` to get a random letter of type A, B or C. But with this code it just gives me the letter object. `Letter.apply` gives me A, B or C but is ugly.

If I change the `apply` function to be `apply()` then things are a little better as I can then use `Letter()` to get one of my random letters, but `Letter` still gives me the object.

Is there anything I can do so that assigning something to `Letter` actually resolves to one of `LetterA`, `LetterB` or `LetterC`?

Comment: No. How would you be able to tell the difference between a type and a method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer to your question is no, you can't distinguish between Letter.type and Letter.apply, so you need a workaround.

I would suggest you to use Type-Class pattern for it, it's much more extenible than adding random-generating apply method to companion object

```
  trait RandomGenerator[T] {
    def gen: T        
  } 

  implicit object RandomLetter extends RandomGenerator[Letter] {

    private val rnd = new Random()

    def gen = (rnd.nextInt(3) + 1) match {
      case 1 => new LetterA
      case 2 => new LetterB
      case 3 => new LetterC
    }
  }

  def random[T: RandomGenerator]: T = 
    implicitly[RandomGenerator[T]].gen


  println(random[Letter])
  println(random[Letter])
  println(random[Letter])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could provide an implicit conversion from `Letter.type` to `Letter` in the companion object:

```
implicit def asLetter(companion: Letter.type): Letter = companion.apply
```

Then you can use `Letter` to get an object that can be implicitly converted to the `Letter` class.  For example:

```
val x: Letter = Letter
val letters: Seq[Letter] = Seq.fill(10)(Letter)
```

But remember that this way you'll always have to ascribe the object to the class in use.

Note: I don't think this is a particularly good idea, but I just wanted to show that it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

You could turn `Letter` into a `def` (on the package object if necessary). For simplicity I wrap things in an outer object:

```
object Letters {
  // Your class definitions
  def Letter = RNG.d(3) match {
    case 1 => new LetterA
    case 2 => new LetterB
    case 3 => new LetterC
  }
}
```

Having a `def` with an upper-case name is not very idiomatic, but IMO acceptable for the sake of some DSL.